# Как сделать обход в ширину и поиск компонент связности через матрицу смежности?

Tags: матрицы, графы, очередь

У меня вершины графа являются объектами класса Vertex. Нужно реализовать обход в ширину и поиск компонент связности через матрицу смежности matrix. Имеющийся код ничего не выводит в консоль, в чем проблема?

```
public void DFS(ref int?[,] matrix, Vertex s)
        {
            int k = Vertexes.IndexOf(s);
            mark[k] = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < Vertexes.Count; ++i)
            {
                int nxt = (int)matrix[k,i];
                if (!mark[nxt])
                {
                    DFS(ref matrix, nxt);
                }
            }
        }

    public void BFS(ref int?[,] matrix, Vertex s) //обход в ширину
        {
            bool[] mark = new bool[Vertexes.Count];
            int p = Vertexes.IndexOf(s);
            Queue<int> Q = new Queue<int>();
            Q.Enqueue(p);
            mark[p] = true;
            while (Q.Count > 0)
            {
                int u = Q.Dequeue();
                for (int i = 0; i < Vertexes.Count; ++i)
                {
                    if (matrix[u, i] == 1 && !mark[i])
                    {
                        mark[i] = true;
                        Q.Enqueue(i);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
public int connectedbfs(ref int?[,] matrix)
        {
            int cnt = 0;
            bool[] mark = new bool[Vertexes.Count];
            while (true)
            {
                foreach (Vertex v in Vertexes)
                {
                    int m = Vertexes.IndexOf(v);
                    if (!mark[m])
                    {
                        BFS(ref matrix, v);
                        ++cnt;
                    }

                }
                return cnt;
            }
        }
```

Comment: А почему  `if (matrix[u, i]==0` ? Наличие ребра обычно не нулём обозначается. На что вам E? У вас реализовано `s.Equals` строк для класса Vertex?

Comment: @MBo убрал метод GetIndex и встал другой вопрос (поправил тему)

Comment: `ничего не выводит в консоль` -  может, нужно в код добавить вывод в консоль?

Comment: @MBo выводит количество вершин, а не количество компонент связности(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Массивов mark два, и оба локальные.

В connectedbfs свой массив проверяется, но никогда не помечается.

А всё, что случается в BFS - там же и остаётся. Ну почти как в бойцовском клубе...

Должен быть один общий (глобальный) массив.

Comment: Спасибо, Тайлер Дерден)

Comment: Извините за наглость, а как сделать реализацию DFS? Код добавил в тему, там в качестве аргументов передаются матрица и вершина Vertex, а внутри алгоритма нужно передать int nxt.

Comment: А почему у вас всё время путаница с числами и объектами? Зачем вообще эти Vertex, если вся информация есть в матрице смежности? Работайте с одними индексами.

Comment: Если вопрос о **D**FS, то реализация точно такая же, как для BFS, только вместо очереди стек.